# Ubuntu migrate from HDD to SSD

Tags: upgrade, ssd, hardware

My old HP becomes quite rusty so I want to add an SSD alongside the HDD, but I don't won't to lose all my data.

I would like to transfer all the application and root folders to the SSD so the OS will boot from it. However, the `/home` directory should remain on the HDD because is to large for the SSD.

I'm not a newbie in Linux, but I certainly don't have enough experience to accomplish the task.

So I would like if someone could make a detailed guide on how to do it. The workflow should roughly be something as follow:

1. Create a back up so I can always revert all the changes
2. Migrate from the SSD to the HDD (selecting a file system, linking the home dir, BIOS settings etc.)
3. Updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to the latest version

**EDIT**
Here is the `lsblk /dev/sda` (HDD) output (the SSD is not plugged yet):

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 923,1G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Comment: If new SSD, I would just do a new install. You cannot have duplicate UUID, so copy of system can be done, but also have to change one system's UUID and any reference to UUID in system. Also since /home is in another system, difficult to use. Better to migrate to its own partition first, if you have space. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Then during new install using Something Else you can mount /home partition. Just be sure NOT to check format box on /home partition.

Comment: Possibly BACK UP, install the SSD alongside the HDD and install a fresh copy of your current version of Ubuntu on the SSD then copy these directories `/bin /sbin /etc /usr /var /lib /tmp /root` except `/etc/fstab` from the old HDD to the SSD installation then upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu. If all goes well, cleanup everything on the HDD leaving only `/home`. Probably this is the closest to what you want... the easy way

Comment: I actually did it for myself couple months ago, let me know what's the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: @Ravexina I add it to the question.. Sorry for the late response

Comment: @oldfred can you maybe write a detailed answer.... Thank you!

Comment: @dmak2709 - I dont know if modern external harddisks with "timeshift" button are downward compatible to any computer or hardware? Timeshift might be optimized for Windows systems? It could be then a risk for non-Windows-Systems?

Comment: @dmak2709 despite the fact you want to upgrade to last  version, I suggest you to do a fresh install!

Answer (score 2):

this might not be the go-to way to do it but here is what I would do:

1. Create a backup using timeshift on an external drive. I find it to be the best backup solution out there and I trust it because I have done this procedure using it dozens of times.

You can install it using [these instructions](https://www.fossmint.com/backup-restore-linux-with-timeshift/)

After that just follow the GUI instructions to create a backup of all your files. Create a second one if you want to be absolutely safe.

2. Put the SSD into your laptop and take the HDD out
3. Install the Linux Distro of your choice.
4. Install timeshift in that Distro
5. Recover the data.
6. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Please read first to the end.
For this procedure it would be better to be disconnected from the internet.

The SSD must not be smaller than the old hard disk. A USB adapter cable for an SSD costs about 20-30 €. Then you could take over the data with:

Plug your SSD to adapter and then USB cable to your Linux machine.

In case the old hard disk is `/dev/sda` (source disk) and the SSD
is `/dev/sdb` (target disk).

(Check yourself which drive is where. You could look after
with GParted.)

Type in terminal:

```
sudo su
```

As root then do in terminal :

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

Command dd is secure and stable.
`dd` makes here a 1 to 1 copy of your hard disk to your SSD, when both have the size of 1 TB or when the SSD is bigger than 1TB - then free space stays free. dd is even backing up the deleted files on the old hard disk to the SSD, so you could recover them on the SSD.

This lasts a longer while, because of USB with it doing we say
20 or 30 MB each second.

It could last 1 to 3 hours.

A backup of old hard disk to new hard disk is working the same. 
And the new hard disk as target must not be smaller than the old hard disk as source.